# Script part of .vue files gets formatted by Vetur but without the use of Prettier

Tags: vue.js, prettier, vetur

Setup: New vue-cli 3.0 project w/ Typescript, ESlint
Active plugins in VSCode: Vetur, Prettier

I checked all the settings I could find and experimented back and fro but couldn't solve the following issue:

Prettier formats the project's `.ts` files without any issues. In my `.vue` files Vetur uses **prettyhtml** for the template part which works fine too. For the script (`lang="ts"`) part though, Vetur formats it based on some rules I cannot find anywhere - but definitely not Prettier/Prettier config. E.g. I changed `singleQuotes = true` and `semi = false` in my Prettier settings which works fine for my `.ts` files but within the script part in my `.vue` files it will just auto-format to double quotes and semi-colons.

Any idea why Vetur isn't relying on Prettier for the script part of `.vue` files? Also, where are the settings applied to that part (e.g. singleQuotes true/false)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add a local .prettierrc file with { "singleQuote": true }, formatting will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to edit Prettier options for Vetur is by adding this to your VSCode `settings.json`:

```
"vetur.format.defaultFormatterOptions": {
  "prettier": {
    "semi": false
  }
}
```